# jQuery .fail and .done not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to show a message to the user whenever an `ajax` call fails. **Method 1** works perfectly both when server responds successfully and when it fails to return anything. Having refactored the code as shown in **method 2**, it doesn't work as expected in the case of server failure: first *'Success'* is alerted and then *'Sorry. Server unavailable.'* is shown. Any idea?

**Method 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var showInfo = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    </script>
    <form id="register" method="post" action="">
        <input id="name" name="name" />
        <input id="join" type="submit" value="register" />
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var $reg = $('#register');
            $reg.on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post('Home/AddUser', null)
                    // ----------------- Method 1 ---------------------
                    .done(
                        function () { alert('Success'); }
                        )
                    .fail(
                        function () { alert('Sorry. Server unavailable.');}
                        );
                    // --- End ---
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var showInfo = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    </script>
    <form id="register" method="post" action="">
        <input id="name" name="name" />
        <input id="join" type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
     <script>
        $(function () {
            var $reg = $('#register');
            $reg.on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post('Home/AddUser', null)
                    // ----------------- Method 2 ---------------------
                    .done(
                        showInfo('Success') 
                        )
                    .fail(
                        showInfo('Sorry. Server unavailable.')
                        );
                    // --- End ---
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You moved the action out of the callback ... there is a difference between `function() {whatever();}` and `whatever()`. The latter will be immediately executed and should return a function reference for the callback (but it doesn't in your case), the former will only be executed as a callback

Comment: why so many downvotes ? Yes it's a simple problem (and a duplicate) but -4 is excessive here, especially for a new user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference as the param to done/fail method which will be invoked once the ajax request is completed successfully/failed.

In your case you are invoking the showInfo and is passing value returned by it as the parameter to done/fail

```
$(function () {
    var $reg = $('#register');
    $reg.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('Home/AddUser', null)
        // ----------------- Method 2 ---------------------
        //need to pass a callback function which will call the alert
        .done(function () {
            showInfo('Success')
        })

            .fail(function () {
            showInfo('Sorry. Server unavailable.')
        });
        // --- End ---
    });
});
```

Comment: `Function#bind` could be handy here too, e.g. `.done(showInfo.bind(null, 'Success'))`

Comment: @Hans yes, but you are invoking it by adding `()` at its end